⌊a/2⌋+⌊a/3⌋+⌊a/5⌋ = a
I found this problem in my elementary number theory textbook.
find all the integers 'a' such that ⌊a/2⌋+⌊a/3⌋+⌊a/5⌋ = a
I did try viewing each of ⌊a/2⌋, ⌊a/3⌋, ⌊a/5⌋ as the number of multiple of 2, 3, and 5 not exceeding a. But I couldn't get any further. please help me solve it.
thank you.

Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts? mathjax might be useful.

I might try breaking it into cases with $a=30b+c$ since $30$ is the lcm of $2,3,5$.

$a$ can't be too large, otherwise $⌊a/2⌋+⌊a/3⌋+⌊a/5⌋ \approx ⌊31a/30⌋ > a$. We need the whole parts to cancel out the fractional part. So checking each number consecutively is not necessarily a bad approach.

On a practical note, the problem with "no clue" questions like this one is that it gives us very little information on what type of solution is appropriate for you.  The fact that $\frac{30}2 + \frac{30}3 + \frac{30}5 - 30 \neq 0$ means that an exhaustive search would work.  Is that what you were studying in the section in which this problem appeared?

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.  In the article, I suggest that you focus on the Edit-Tools section.
